# Office 2010 won't open after Japanese era updates

Tags: updates, microsoft-office-2010

In January 2019, after an update, whenever I try to open Excel 2010, Word 2010, etc. I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point EnumCalendarInfoExEx could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

After clicking `OK` twice (an identical message box pops up again), the last message box says:

> The operating system is not presently configured to run this application.

I had a similar error in December, and after uninstalling one of the recent updates to do with the upcoming new Japanese era, it started working again. Microsoft since disabled that update, and released a new version that allowed Office 2010 to run.

This was the error message in December 2018:

> The procedure entry point GetDateFormatEx could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

I've tried uninstalling all updates to do with the new Japanese era, and I've also run a repair installation of Office 2010, but the error still persists. Microsoft doesn't seem to have fixed this new update bug yet.

How can I get Office 2010 to run again?

Answer (score 1):

According to this Microsoft article, KB441614 caused the problem and KB4462157 fixes it. I have clients having this problem so I am in the midst of trying to solve it. I have yet to set up a VM to test it on the appropriate versions though. I will update this answer with any more info as I get it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462157/january-18-2019-update-for-office-2010-kb4462157

Comment: That was the update I uninstalled in December that fixed the problem.